# EmptyEnumerable<T>.Instance assignment and multi-threading design

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.5

This is more of a design question I guess than an actual bug or a rant. I wonder what people think about the following behavior:

In .NET, when you want to represent an empty IEnumerable efficiently you can use `Enumerable.Empty<MyType>()`, this will cache the empty enumerable instance. It's a nice and free micro-optimization I guess that could help if relied upon heavily.

However, this is how the implementation looks like:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Empty<TResult>() {
    return EmptyEnumerable<TResult>.Instance;
}


internal class EmptyEnumerable<TElement>
{
    static volatile TElement[] instance;

    public static IEnumerable<TElement> Instance {
        get {
            if (instance == null) instance = new TElement[0];
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect the assignment to happen within a lock, after another null check, but that's not what happens.

I wonder if this is a conscious decision (i.e. we don't care of potentially creating several objects we will just throw away immediately if this is accessed concurrently, because we would rather avoid locking) or just ignorance?

What would you do?

Comment: A lock is rather expensive operation while creating an empty array is much cheaper - even if you manage to call this code on 8 threads parallel, it will still be faster to create 8 arrays.

Comment: this is what I was assuming, was hoping for an evidence of this being a conscious decision though. Besides, there's also performance penalty for using volatile, which is pretty much redundant in this scenario.

Comment: you would need `volatile` even with `lock` (otherwise the !null-lock-!null routine may actually not be thread-safe.

Comment: Personally I'd have expected a type initializer in `EmptyEnumerable<TElement>`... no need for a lock *or* a volatile field...

Comment: @JonSkeet me too. Do you know if that would have had more overhead? That static initializer safety must come with a price.

Comment: @JonSkeet In that case the lock wouldn't be explicit, but it'd be there just the same.  The whole idea of this optimization *is to not actually synchronize the initialization of this object* because the cost of synchronization is greater than then negative effects of the race condition.

Comment: @Servy: It would be there in a way that the CLR has deep knowledge of, and can optimize for, with no "check whether or not we need to lock by seeing whether we can see a non-null reference". I don't think the cost of a non-beforefieldinit type initializer is really worth worrying about, personally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is safe because `volatile` sequences all reads and writes to that field. Before the read in `return instance;` there is always at least one write setting that field to a valid value.

It is unclear *what* value is going to be returned because multiple arrays can potentially be created here. But there will always be a non-null array.

**Why** did they do it? Well, a lock has more overhead than `volatile` and the implementation is easy enough to pull off. Those extra instances will only be created a few times if multiple threads happen to race to this method. For each thread racing at most one instance will be created. After initialization is complete there is zero garbage.

---

Note, that without volatile the instance field can flip back to zero after having been assigned. That is very counter intuitive. Without any synchronization the compiler is allowed to rewrite the code like that:

```
var instanceRead1 = instance;
var returnValue;
if (instanceRead1 == null) {
    returnValue = new TElement[0];
    instance = returnValue;
}

var instanceRead2 = instance;
if (instanceRead2 == returnValue) return instanceRead2;
else return null;
```

In the presence of concurrent writes `instanceRead2` can be a different value than was just written. No compiler would do such a rewrite but it is legal. The CPU *might* do something like that on some architectures. Unlikely, but legal. Maybe there is a more plausible rewrite.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting this isn't safe, I was asking why they preferred allowing multiple instances for being created and thrown to GC right away rather than ensuring only once instance is created and returned (by using a lock).

Comment: besides, even without volatile this still would be safe

Comment: @synhershko without volatile there are strange effects on weak memory models. `instance` could flip back to null even if your own thread had written a non-null value. The effects are really surprising.

Comment: Because GC allocation is so cheap, its almost like sp++. And lock test takes several cycles. Volatile is barrier, Lock uses xchgcmp in a loop (it can put threads to sleep and yield the processor making a context switch, this can't happen on barrier alone, ignoring quantum expiration), it's more costly from processor point of view.

Comment: @LuizFelipe those extra instances will only be created a few times if multiple threads happen to race to this method. After that, zero garbage.

Comment: Yes, it's negligible memory loss for such infrequently condition.

Comment: @usr I wonder if you have references to that phenomenon of `instance` potentially flipping back to null again?

Comment: @synhershko Without `volatile` nothing is preventing any of those operations from being reordered without restriction.  The `return` can be moved to be before the assignment, at least as is observed by another thread.

Comment: @synhershko "wasn't suggesting is isn't safe".  What does the "not thread-safe" in the title of this question mean then?

Comment: @synhershko I'll post it here if I manage to find it. So far without success.

Comment: @PeterRitchie forgot about the title, was changing the question while typing :)

Comment: @synhershko I have posted a compiler rewrite that demonstrates the problem. Very contrived, alas. I couldn't come up with something better.

Comment: @synhershko Seems to me, if you've changed the question that much, it was actually answered.  Seems your now looking for opinions...

Comment: @usr thanks, this has been very educative. Virtual points to Jon Skeet as well.

Answer (score 0):

In that code there is the possibility of creating more than one array.  It's possible to either have a thread create an array and then end up actually using the one created from another thread, or for two different threads to each end up with their own array.  However, *that just doesn't matter here*.  The code will work correctly *whether multiple objects are created or not*.  As long as *an* array is returned it doesn't matter *which* array is returned by any call ever.  Additionally the "expense" of creating an empty array is simply not very high.  The decision was made (likely after a fair bit of testing) that the expense of synchronizing access to the field every time the field is accessed ever was greater than the very unlikely possibility that a couple of additional empty arrays were created.

This is not a pattern that you should emulate in your own (quasi) singletons unless you are also in the position in which creating a new instance is cheap, and creating multiple instances doesn't affect the functionality of the code.  In effect the only situation in which this works is when you're trying to cache the value of a cheaply computed operation.  That's a micro optimization; it's not wrong, but it's also not a big win either.

Answer (score 0):

Although running benchmarks on such small code not really yields the most trustworthy results, here are few options compared (very bluntly though):

1. The current implementation with `volatile instance` and null check without lock.
2. A lock on `static object syncRoot`.
3. Static type initializer.
4. A lock on `typeof(T)` (so that there is no static type initializer created).

Results (seconds for 1 billion iterations):

1. 21.7
2. 28.8
3. 20.3
4. 29.3

As you can see, the `lock` approach is the worst one by far. The best would be static type initializer which would also make the code cleaner. The actual reason is probably not really because of the lock but rather the size of the getter and things like code inlining and more options for the compiler to optimize the code.

The speed of creating 1 million (not billion this time) empty arrays for the same machine is 26ms.

The code:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleSandbox
{
    class T1<T>
    {
        static volatile T[] _instance;
        public static T[] Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_instance == null) _instance = new T[0];
                return _instance;
            }
        }
    }

    class T2<T>
    {
        static T[] _instance;
        static object _syncRoot = new object();
        public static T[] Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_instance == null) 
                    lock (_syncRoot)
                        if (_instance == null)
                            _instance = new T[0];
                return _instance;
            }
        }
    }

    class T3<T>
    {
        static T[] _instance = new T[0];
        public static T[] Instance
        {
            get
            {
                return _instance;
            }
        }
    }

    class T4<T>
    {
        static T[] _instance;
        public static T[] Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                    lock (typeof(T4<T>))
                        if (_instance == null)
                            _instance = new T[0];
                return _instance;
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[][] res = new int[2][];
            var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();

            for (var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
                res[i % 2] = T1<int>.Instance;

            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            sw.Restart();

            for (var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
                res[i % 2] = T2<int>.Instance;

            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            sw.Restart();

            for (var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
                res[i % 2] = T3<int>.Instance;

            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            sw.Restart();

            for (var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
                res[i % 2] = T4<int>.Instance;

            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            sw.Restart();

            for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
                res[i % 2] = new int[0];

            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            Console.WriteLine(res[0]);
            Console.WriteLine(res[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, why is creating empty arrays just as fast as using a static initializer. A single CPU core shouldn't be able to allocate 3 billion arrays per seconds. That's too quick. This smells like the loop body was optimized out. Look at the disassembly and post it here.

Comment: This isn't really a meaningful test.  First off, since you get the result but never use it the compiler is free to optimize the call away entirely so long as it can prove there are no side effects that could be observed.  My guess is that's happening in the 3rd case and not the others.  On top of that, you're test is primarily just fetching an already initialized value.  That is meaningful to know, but it's also important to test the initialization time, compare contested and uncontested locks, etc.  Alone this test data really means nothing.

Comment: @usr - you are right, it did optimize it out - made a little change to get some idea on the speed of initialization. I applied the same "trick" to the rest of the cases to make sure it actually executed the code. The results are updated but still show the same trend. Of course it might be that the compiler still is just tricking me

Comment: Now lit looks like the modulo operator overhead dominates the test. The lock test and the unsynchronized test should be farther apart. Modulo is as expensive as a division. Very expensive. Like 15-30 cycles. Better use `int sum = 0; ... sum += result.Length; ... GC.KeepAlive(sum);` But even then the loaded value can be cached.

Comment: modulo isn't the culprit - `x = x == 0 ? 1 : 0; res[x] = ...` is even slower (I suspect that CPU knows how to optimize `%2`as a special case). It is more likely that the slowdown is because multiple arrays are stored and it changes how GC handles it.

Comment: @usr - I think that the actual nuances are how compiler can optimize/inline the code - for example, if I change the lock sample to `if (!=null)return; lock()...` - it is about 8% faster than the usual `if (==null)lock{if(==null)set}return;`.

Comment: @Knaģis you could be right. This is hard to benchmark. At least the benchmark isn't totally meaningless. Just lots of noise/overhead.